# Inno Setup MsgBox with three buttons and three outcomes

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to create a `MsgBox` with three buttons and three outcomes, but am unable to see how I can create the third outcome? I currently have the following code for a two button `MsgBox`, which works perfectly:

```pascal
if ((strExistingInstallPath <> '') and (strExistingVersion = '2.5.3')) then
begin
  if SuppressibleMsgBox('Setup has detected that ' + strMyAppName + ' ' + strExistingVersion + '.' + strExistingBuild + ' is installed.' + #13#10 + #13#10 +
    'The existing version must be removed before installing or upgrading to ' + strMyAppVersion + '.' + strMyAppBuild + '.' + #13#10 + #13#10 +
    'Would you like Setup to uninstall the existing version?',
    mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO, IDYES) = IDYES then
    begin
      Exec(GetUninstallString, '', '', SW_SHOW,
        ewWaitUntilTerminated, intResultCode);
      Result := True;
    end else
      begin
        MsgBox('The existing version must be removed first.' + #13#10 +
          'Setup is unable to continue. Setup will now exit.',
          mbError, MB_OK);
        Result := False;
      end;
end;
```

If I change the `MB_YESNO` to `MB_YESNOCANCEL`, I now get three buttons, *Yes*, *No* and *Cancel*. However, since the `if` statement is assigned to the `MsgBox`, I'm struggling to work out how to do an `else if IDCANCEL then` type statement. I tried to assign the ID constant returned by the MsgBox to a string and then create separate if statements for the string being equal to each ID constant, but this failed miserably. What am I missing here? Ideally, I would like the three buttons be labelled as *Yes*, *No* and *Silent*, so that the third button can be given a `/silent` parameter to prevent the uninstall prompt. So, is it possible to rename the buttons as well?

Comment: MsgBox returns an integer, you can use a 'case' on its return.

Comment: That was my problem. I didn't realise MsgBox returned an integer. The ID constants look like strings!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could write multiple `if` statements, but you'd have to store the returned value into a variable and check that variable value. But as @Sertac mentioned in his comment, you can use a `case` statement, which better describes the aim in your code, for instance:

```pascal
case SuppressibleMsgBox('Text', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNOCANCEL, IDYES) of
  IDYES:
  begin
    { user pressed Yes }
  end;
  IDNO:
  begin
    { user pressed No }
  end;
  IDCANCEL:
  begin
    { user pressed Cancel }
  end;
end;
```

Out of curiosity with multiple `if` statements it could be:

```pascal
var
  MsgResult: Integer;
begin
  MsgResult := SuppressibleMsgBox('Text', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNOCANCEL, IDYES);

  if MsgResult = IDYES then
  begin
    { user pressed Yes }
  end
  else
  if MsgResult = IDNO then
  begin
    { user pressed No }
  end
  else
  if MsgResult = IDCANCEL then
  begin
    { user pressed Cancel }
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. You second example with if statements is exactly what I had done previously, but using a string! Working now I realise that it should have been an integer.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to change the label on the buttons from Cancel to Silent?

Comment: Behind the `SuppressibleMsgBox` (and `MsgBox`) functions is the [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows API function which builds the dialog. And that function gets button captions from the currently selected language and provides no way to use custom captions. But yes, I think [`it should be possible`](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/messagebox/article.php/c10873/MessageBox-with-Custom-Button-Captions.htm), but you'd need to have an external library with a hook. It would be easier to make a custom form for this.

Comment: Thanks. However, I have actually now found a more elegant solution for what I was trying to achieve, in that even when you need a third outcome, which I want to be the default option when the /verysilent switch is used from the commandline, you actually don't need to display a third button. You can still have a MB_YESNO, but give it a different default value e.g. IDIGNORE and call that when running silently.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final code in case it is useful for anyone else:

```pascal
var
  intMsgBoxResult: Integer;
if ((strExistingInstallPath <> '') and (strExistingVersion = '2.5.3')) then
begin
  intMsgBoxResult := SuppressibleMsgBox('Setup has detected that ' + strMyAppName + ' ' + strExistingVersion + '.' + strExistingBuild + ' is installed.' + #13#10 + #13#10 +
    'The existing version must be removed before installing or upgrading to ' + strMyAppVersion + '.' + strMyAppBuild + '.' + #13#10 + #13#10 +
    'Would you like Setup to uninstall the existing version?',
    mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO, IDIGNORE);
  if intMsgBoxResult = IDYES then
    begin
      Exec(GetUninstallString, '/silent', '', SW_SHOW,
        ewWaitUntilTerminated, intResultCode);
      Result := True;
    end;
  if intMsgBoxResult = IDNO then 
    begin
      MsgBox('The existing version must be removed first.' + #13#10 +
        'Setup is unable to continue. Setup will now exit.',
        mbError, MB_OK);
      Result := False;
    end;
  if intMsgBoxResult = IDIGNORE then
    begin
      Exec(GetUninstallString, '', '', SW_SHOW,
        ewWaitUntilTerminated, intResultCode);
      Result := True;
    end; 
end;
```

Comment: Case is better here. But anyway, now you are testing the `intMsgBoxResult` value always for 3 times. If you really want to use `if`, then add at least `else` (as I've shown) because if the `intMsgBoxResult` value will be `IDYES`, there is no need to test is also for `IDNO` and `IDIGNORE`.

Comment: Good point. Will make the amendments and might switch to using case instead if you think it is a better way of handling it. Really grateful for the help and advice.