# Inno Setup Show MessageBox when Cancel button is clicked

Tags: inno-setup

How to make a message box on the Cancel button?

https://4sysops.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Yes-No-prompt.png

Answer (score 1):

Implement the [`CancelButtonClick` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CancelButtonClick).

```pascal
[Code]

procedure CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
begin
  MsgBox('Cancel button was clicked', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Set the `Cancel` and `Confirm` out parameters to make Inno Setup proceed as you need.

Comment: And can we know that? Ask a good question to get what you want.

Comment: See also [Inno Setup MsgBox with three buttons and three outcomes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25515610/850848).

Comment: So edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: @Zasanialhodda: Martin has answered the specific question you asked, and given you a good working example of displaying a messagebox when the cancel button is clicked. You should be able to read the documentation for the MsgBox function to figure out how to make it display specific icons and buttons.

Comment: What do we do with that?

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow, you have to be able to describe the problem clearly, in the question text (not in the comments), to make it indexable and searchable, so others with the same problem can find the answer too. + You obviously need some behavior too. So far you have only described us some message box. But not what it should do.

Comment: What is not clear ?